# How to fetch id of this element to remove from array in react hooks?

Tags: react-hooks

I'm having an array of components (component is child looped in the parent) added each component has a remove function attached to it

parent.js

```
          ///loop runn ,components push to array
          <AddSet key={i} id={i} count={count}/>
```

child.js

```
          function handleRemove()
            {//here i wanna pass to parent the id od the div i click onto}
      //return
                <div id={props.id}>
                        <TextBox/>
                        <Button onClick={handleRemove()} >-</Button>
                <div>
```

My need is when I click the button(-) I wanna pass to the parent id of "this" div.

I've googled but not found the solution.

Can anyone please help me out with this any help is appreciate .

Is it the right approach I'm working onto or are their any other best practices?

Comment: I think you are looking for `onClick={() => handleRemove(props.id)}`.

Comment: @Alvaro yeah right. but the thing is when props passed and click the function doesn't call as the function had been called when rendering the component

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

Very similar to what you have described.

```js
const arr = [
  {label: 'divA', id: 'divA'},
  {label: 'divB', id: 'divB'},
  {label: 'divC', id: 'divC'}
];

function App() {
  console.log('Rendering App...');
  
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(['divA','divB','divC']);
 
  const divItems = arr.map((item,index) => {
    if (active.indexOf(item.id) >= 0) {
      return (
        <ChildDiv
          id={item.id}
          label={item.label}
          setActive={setActive}
        />
      );
    }
  });
  

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      {divItems}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function ChildDiv(props) {
  
  function removeDiv(id) {
    console.log('Removing ' + id);
    props.setActive((prevState) => {
      const aux = Array.from(prevState);
      return aux.filter((item) => {
        return item !== id;
      });
    });
  }

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>
        {props.label}
      </div>
      <button onClick={()=>removeDiv(props.id)}>Remove</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Actually component is child called in parent everthing is not in the same component

Comment: I see. The remove is in child, but state of "active" childs it in the parent, right?

Comment: yeah right that array is in parent i wanna just pass the id of this click remove button then using the id i'll filter thr array in parent

Comment: Updated the answer. You can pass the `setState` function to your Child component. React guarantee that the `setState` function's reference will be the same on every render. Then you can use it in your `remove()` method.

Comment: actually that removal must be done on click of the button not div

Comment: There you go. I've added the button. See if that helps.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work i did try that . the thing is when props passed and click the function doesn't call as the function had been called when rendering the component

Comment: You've got to add a bigger part of your code to the question. So we can see what is going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204403/discussion-between-tested-and-cbdeveloper).

Answer (score 0):

-

updated to

handleRemove(props.id)} >- ////worked